# window dot open hides half the newly opened window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a new window after an on click event but i am having a problem. Half of the opened window is hidden on the right most side of the desktop, i am having to drag it so i could see it.

This is my code :

```
 if ($j==0){echo "<a   onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'','resizable=yes,location=no,scrollbars=yes,dependent=yes,width=1000,height=900,status'); return false\" href='display_offer_GP.php?CodeOfferReflet=$row[7]&CodeOfferArtemis=$row[8]'><img id='m_$i'BORDER=0 src=\"images/loupe.gif\" ></a>&nbsp;
" ;
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening ? thank you

EDIT: i don't to find a solution for this because that i know how to do, what i want is to understand why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
function openPopup(url)
{
    var x = screen.width/2 - 700/2;
    var y = screen.height/2 - 450/2;
    window.open(url, 'Test','height=485,width=700,left='+x+',top='+y);
}
```